# Navbar causing other components to not load in React Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I am setting up a basic navbar, it just has some buttons, not any complex log or anything. When I have this navbar inside of the switch, no other componet loads, meaning I cannot wrap the navbar between certain components, when I have the navbar outside of the switch , then it works, and I can just check if props.match.location etc is "/" and not load it on homepage, so I found a workaround, but what could be causing this bug, or is it expected behavious, I suspect my wildroutes, but not 100% sure what . 
Where I am using navbar

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route component={theNavbar} />

                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />

                    <Route exact path="/api/:city/electronics" component={Electronics} />
                    <Route exact path="/api/:city/labour" component={Labour} />

                    <Route exact path="/api/posts/item/:id" component={ItemDetails} />

                    <Route exact path="/create/:city/:category" component={CreatePost} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: I've rolled back your [edit]. It is not acceptable to replace your question content with noise, particularly after you've received and accepted an answer. Once posted here, the content belongs to SO according to the terms of service of this site. See the [help] for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's completely expected behavior, and caused by a couple of factors. First is the `Switch`, and the second is the match anything `Route` for the nav.

**[`Switch`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch)**

> Renders the **first** child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the
>   location.

All subsequent matches won't render at all.

**[`Route path`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string-string)**

> Routes without a path always match.

`<Route component={theNavbar} />`

This route matches all locations and thus will always match. Being listed first within a `Switch` means it will always render.

The solution to always render *some* navigation component while still matching *other* routes is to move that component outside of the `Switch` but still within the `Router`.

Comment: that makes total sense, but what would be best practice if I did not want to render it in the homepage? currently on the navbar I am telling it, "hey if props.location.pathname is "/" , render null " seems to work fine, does this seem like a "hack" or a good solution

Comment: That is similar approach to a header component I use in a production app for a company I work with. Our header component actually renders several different elements depending on the route.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior.  Per the [React Router documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string-string):

> Routes without a path always match.

So your NavBar will always be matched in the `<Switch>` and none of the other components will render.